# How to prevent entity db context from create a database and tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 website with EF for identity. But i would like to create the database and the database tables using the sql scripts that i generated before. But everytime i will try to login for example the dbcontext creates a new database and the tables (if it not exists). How to just throw an exception and not create if it not exist, and if it exist, just do the login normally.

My context class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
 {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
 }
```

The i tried to override the onmodelCreating method just throwing an exception, but than even if the database exists with the tables, it shows me that exception.

Comment: In your `Application_Start` do you have the instance of your database created and `context.Database.Initialize(true)` invoked?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this inside your context:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationUser>(null);
```

It will turn off database initialization and migrations